# How can I setState for array with nested objects with arrays?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I change the value object inside my array with objects using `setState`? How I have it right now it only add value to the first array I tried mapping all the way down to value but its not working. Any advice would be great. And one more question. I have an `handleClick(event)` that targets the id in my child component. How would you write a function to change the value in the the state using `setState`.

```
React.useEffect(()=> {
      if(start === true){
        
      fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=27&difficulty=easy&type=multiple")
      .then(res => res.json())
      
      .then(data => setState(data.results.map(item =>
      ({selectedQuestion: "",
          buttons: item.incorrect_answers.concat(item.correct_answer).map(item => 
            ({use: item, value: false, id: uuidv4()})),
          questions: item.question   
          
      }))))
    }} , [start])
  function startGame () {  
    setStart(prevState => !prevState)
}
const myButtons = state.map(function(item) { 
  return (<Quiz 
  key={uuidv4()}
  buttons={item.buttons}
  question = {item.questions}
  handleClick ={(event) =>handleClick(event.target.id)}

/> ) })
  console.log(state)
    let myFlat = state.map(item => item.buttons.map(item => item.id))
    let finalFlat = myFlat.flat()
    
  function handleClick (event) {
    for(let i = 0; i<finalFlat.length; i++){
if(finalFlat[i] === event){
  setState(item => item.map(item =>({
    ...item, value:true
  })))
}}}
```

Comment: setting state in react is not something new. you should do some researches before asking.

Comment: What is the state you are trying to update? What does the state look like? Please include a more complete [mcve].

Comment: The one with the objects in it. There are only two states and only one has objects.

Comment: Sorry, we're only asking for you to make it easier for people volunteering their time to help you for free. I don't see any state variables declared in your code snippet. Along with making a more complete [mcve] can you also fix the formatting so it's easier to read? You also appear to ask more than one question, can you edit your post to ask a single, focused question about a specific issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.assign to replace only parts of an map:

```
> obj = {"arr1": [1,2,3], "arr2": [9]}
{ arr1: [ 1, 2, 3 ], arr2: [ 9 ] }

> Object.assign(obj, {"arr1": [1,2,3,4]})
{ arr1: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], arr2: [ 9 ] }
```

Also, In react you shoud use setState to change state.